# What kind of Machine learning category does this fall under?

Tags: machine-learning

My problem statement is this: The user is facing a problem. The user inputs a basic description of the problem Based on keywords in the input by user, the program would ask more specific questions to find out more about the problem. Then based on that, the program would ask questions more specific to the keywords provided in the second answer.

In the end the program will be able to produce a detailed description of the problem that the user is facing.

My question is that I am trying to do this via machine learning and what to know what category this falls under.

Is it Neural networks or supervised or unsupervised or completely something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that this is related to Natural Language Processing (NLP). It is a category that deals with text understanding and human-computer interaction using natural languages. There exists both deep learning methods that uses neural networks in addition to some statistical methods. Your task is similar to a Chatbot I guess. With a quick search I found this:
https://uxplanet.org/nlp-vs-ci-who-is-the-king-of-chatbot-2f9d2e09f085. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. But, I am trying to give answer based on my understanding.

My general guess is that, you are talking about a chatbot which try to generate a problem description by continuing conversation with an user. It falls under the category of natural language processing (NLP).

Q. **Is it Neural networks or supervised or unsupervised or completely something else?**

- It depends on how do you model your problem in terms of data. If you have data then you can formulate it as a supervised problem, and can use neural network to solve it.

But, I suspect you don't have the dataset for this particular task. In that case, you can look into many question-answer datasets. Otherwise, the problem can be solved in a algorithmic way too, in that case, no data is required.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand a user is interacting with a bot. If that is the case it is related to **Natural Language Processing**(NLP) as the data is in unstructured form i.e. text data. These type of data can be solved with either Supervised Learning or you can use Neural Network depending upon the complexity of the data and what is your objective.